# iptables unable to use same target

Tags: iptables

I am unable to use the same target under iptables. can someone help please?

iptables v1.4.21
Kernel: 3.16.7

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SAME --to 1.2.3.4-1.2.3.7
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: Have you created a chain by the name _SAME_? What's the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: It is not a chain but a target

Comment: Are you copying this rule from another computer?

Comment: no it is a new rule. i think that the module ipt_SAME is not available with kernel 3. Has anyone tried to use the SAME as target? My objective is if ip A.A.A.A goes to B.B.B.B it is natted with IP X.X.X.X then if A.A.A.A  re-establishes a session with B.B.B.B it is natted with the same IP X.X.X.X. According to my reseach the module ipt_same does that:
SAME (IPv4-specific)
Similar to SNAT/DNAT depending on  chain:  it  takes  a range  of  addresses  (`--to 1.2.3.4-1.2.3.7') and  gives a client the same source-/destination-address for each connection.

Answer (score 1):

According to [*iptables-extensions*'s man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCV), the `SAME` target was superseded by the `--persistent` flag of the `DNAT` target:

> `--persistent`
>
> > Gives a client the same source-/destination-address for each connection. This supersedes the `SAME` target. Support for persistent mappings is available from *2.6.29-rc2*.